# Drawable.createFromStream() returns null

Tags: android, xml, android-vectordrawable

In my Android Studio project, I created a custom folder called `assets`, which in turn contains another folder called `flags`, which in turn contains a lot of XML files representing SVG images.
Whenever I try to load such XML files and create `Drawable`s from them via the function `Drawable.createFromStream()`, I obtain a `null`.

Here is the code:

```
AssetManager am = getApplicationContext().getAssets();
String[] files = new String[0];
try
{
  files = am.list("flags");
}
catch (IOException e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
// At this point, variable 'files' correctly contains all the names of my XML files
ArrayList<Drawable> drawables = new ArrayList<>();
for (String file : files)
{
  Drawable d = null;
  try
  {
    d = Drawable.createFromStream(am.open("flags/" + file), null);
  }
  catch (IOException e)
  {
    Log.i("EX2", "Second exception: " + file + " not found");
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  drawables.add(d);
  if (d == null) // This message is always printed, but no exception occurs
    Log.i("FLAG", "Null drawable");
}
```

As you can see fromt he code above, the message `Null drawable` is always printed even if the XML file is found (in fact, no exception occurs).

Comment: VectorDrawables are not SVG files. Not any longer.  Referring to them as SVG just causes confusion.

Answer (score 0):

> which in turn contains a lot of XML files representing SVG images

Android has no ability to use SVG files as drawables, whether as assets or anything else. Try [a third-party SVG library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/96) instead of `Drawable.createFromStream()`.

In your case, you do not have SVG files, but rather vector drawables created from those SVG files. Apparently, `Drawable.createFromStream()` does not support those. Or, perhaps you are testing on older devices; `Drawable.createFromStream()` definitely does not support vector drawables on Android 4.4 and older devices. In your case, just store the vector drawables as drawables, not assets.

Comment: That's really strange, since when I import my original SVG files as Vector Asset in Android Studio, it automatically transform them into XML files. In fact, if I store the XML in the `drawable` directory, they are loaded just fine.

Comment: @Michael: Those are vector drawables after the Vector Asset conversion, not SVG files. On Android 4.4 and older devices, `Drawable.createFromStream()` definitely cannot handle vector drawable resources, as vector drawables did not exist and only are available via the Android Support Library. On Android 5.0+, it is at least possible that `createFromStream()` could handle vector drawables from streams. Why do you want these as assets, instead of drawables, where you know that they work properly?

Comment: Well, I read somewhere that storing images (such as SVGs) into the assets folder was preferable, in order to distinguish between the project/Android base images and custom images. But I guess it is better to keep storing them into the `Drawable` directory.

Comment: @Michael: "I read somewhere that storing images (such as SVGs) into the assets folder was preferable, in order to distinguish between the project/Android base images and custom images" -- I do not know where you read that. I would not recommend that practice in general. "But I guess it is better to keep storing them into the Drawable directory" -- agreed.